# Android FB logInWithReadPermissions and registerCallback WITHOUT login button

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

Getting mad with this. I try to login into FB and at the same time retrieve user information.

The FB login works fine, the app changes to FB, shows what permission the app is asking for and after pressing Accept, goes back to my app. BUT the registerCallback is never called. Where is my mistake? here my code:

```
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                this,
                permissionNeeds);

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.e("dd", "SUCCESS");

                        GraphRequest.newMeRequest( loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                   public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                                            System.out.println("ERROR");
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("Success");
                                            try {
                                                String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                                                System.out.println("JSON Result" + jsonresult);
                                                String str_email = json.getString("email");
                                                String str_id = json.getString("id");
                                                String str_firstname = json.getString("first_name");
                                                String str_lastname = json.getString("last_name");
                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).executeAsync();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                        Log.e("dd", "facebook login canceled");

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {


                        Log.e("dd", "facebook login failed error");

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Is this inside of a Fragment or Activity? You need to override the onActivityResult method. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: it is inside Activity. See my edit, as you mention, it was the missing onActivityResult

Answer (score 7):

EDIT:

found it, the following code was missing, now I am getting the user information after login

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```